# Moving Rectangle in SFML, how to make it smoother?

Tags: c++, sfml

This is my code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>


int main()
{

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML Game");
    window.setFramerateLimit(200);

    //Variable that keeps the game loop running
    bool play = true;

    //Event object holding all events
    sf::Event event;

    //States for button/events
    bool Left = false;
    bool Right = false;
    bool space = false;

    //Variables
    int rectXPosition = 375;    //Rectangles X position
    int rectYPosition = 400;    //Rectangles Y position

    //Images
    sf::Texture image1;
    if (image1.loadFromFile("Images/GreekSoldier.png") == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "FAILED!!!" << "\n";
        return 1;
    }

    //Render shapes
    sf::RectangleShape rect;
    rect.setSize(sf::Vector2f(77, 150)); //Width and height
    rect.setPosition(375, 400); //Position
    rect.setFillColor(sf::Color::White); //Color
    rect.setTexture(&image1);

    //Game loop
    while (play == true)
    {
        //EVENTS
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Left)
            {
                //Set the state to true
                Left = true;
            }

            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Right)
            {
                Right = true;
            }

            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space)
            {
                space = true;
            }

            //Event type is window closed
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                //Set play to false in order to stop the game loop
                play = false;
            }
        }

        //LOGIC
        if (Left == true)
        {
            int x = 0;
            for (x = 1; x < 2; x++)
            {   
                rectXPosition-=5; //X position variable of the rectangle
                rect.setPosition(rectXPosition, rectYPosition);
                window.clear();
                window.draw(rect);
                window.display();
                Sleep(5);
            }
            Left = false;
        }

        if (Right == true)
        {
            int x = 0;
            for (x = 1; x < 2; x++)
            {   
                rectXPosition+= 5; //X position variable of the rectangle
                rect.setPosition(rectXPosition, rectYPosition);
                window.clear();
                window.draw(rect);
                window.display();
                Sleep(5);
            }

            Right = false;
        }

        if (space == true)
        {
            int x = 0;
            for (x = 1; x < 15; x++)
            {   
                rectYPosition-= 3; //X position variable of the rectangle
                rect.setPosition(rectXPosition, rectYPosition);
                window.clear();
                window.draw(rect);
                window.display();
                Sleep(10);
            }

            for (x = 1; x < 15; x++)
            {   
                rectYPosition+= 3; //X position variable of the rectangle
                rect.setPosition(rectXPosition, rectYPosition);
                window.clear();
                window.draw(rect);
                window.display();
                Sleep(10);
            }
            space = false;
        }


        //RENDERING
        window.clear();

        //Draw the rectangle shape
        window.draw(rect);
        window.display();
    }

    //Clean up and close the window
    window.close();

    return 0;
}
```

How would I make the movement more smoother? How do I make it so the rectangle(the soldier) can jump and move at the same time? And how do I stop it so, when holding down left it doesn't take 3 seconds for it to actually move?

I've added a youtube video if you guys can't be bothered to compile it and just want to see what I'm talking about.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_JLwGh1Wgo

Comment: The most importan tip for you will be to **not** use `KeyPressed` events for continuous actions.

Comment: What would be a better solution?

Comment: Have a look how the sample are done, esp. [the pong example](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/tree/master/examples/pong). You can find many more interesting things in [SFML Game Development](http://www.packtpub.com/sfml-game-development/book) which I recommend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `KeyPressed` events are generated when someone presses a key and then repeat every so often (but not every frame, which makes it not smooth). They are intended to be used for text input, for example.

Pressing another key will also interrupt the repetition of the events for the previous key, so your other problem has the same cause.

You should handle the `KeyPressed` events only for some instant actions, like pressing a menu button. In this particular example you should get rid of this altogether and use only [`sf::Keyboard`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php#details) by replacing the line:

```
        if (Left == true)
```

with:

```
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
```

and so on...

I would explain why [`sf::Keyboard`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php#details) is the right thing here, but the documentation does it very well.

---

Another big problem is that you have multiple loops that don't let anything else happen in the game. You should get yourself familiar with the concepts of event loops, velocity and gravity (and make corresponding variables).

When the player presses <kbd>Space</kbd> you shouldn't hardcode the character to move N pixels up and N pixels down **while stopping every other possible action in the game**, but instead change the character's vertical velocity and use it to change the character's position in every frame (and also have that velocity be reduced by gravity).

The most important point to take from this is you must have only 1 main event loop that calls `window.display`.